# Upload multiple image to firebase and retrieve into viewpage

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to upload multiple image to firebase and retrieve into view page . I am only able to upload the multiple image but getting only one Uri getdlownload link in Realtime database due to which only one image is fetching into view page

```
enter code here
private void sendDataToFirebase() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    id = databaseReference.push().getKey();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



   photoUri=new Uri[photoUris.size()];
    for (i = 0; i < photoUris.size(); i++) {
       photoUri[i] = photoUris.get(i);
```

//                File fileUriPhoto = new File(SiliCompressor.with(this).
//
//                        compress(FileUtils.getPath(this, photoUri), new File(this.getCacheDir(), "AddPostPhotos")));
//                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileUriPhoto);

```
        String imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final StorageReference imageFolder = mfirebaseStorage.child("AddPost/" + photoUri[i].getLastPathSegment());


            imageFolder.putFile(photoUri[i]).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            addPostModel = new AddPostModel();
                            addPostModel.setCategories(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
                            addPostModel.setSubcategories(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
                            addPostModel.setTitle(name.getText().toString().trim());
                            addPostModel.setAuthor(author.getText().toString().trim());
                            addPostModel.setPrice(price.getText().toString().trim());
                            addPostModel.setDesc(desc.getText().toString().trim());
                            addPostModel.setUserUid(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                            addPostModel.setPhoneNumaber(mCurrentUser.getPhoneNumber());
                            addPostModel.setDateTime(date);
                            addPostModel.setImageUrl(photoUri[i].toString());//Here is the problem//
                            addPostModel.setKey(id);
                            databaseReference.child(id).setValue(addPostModel);



                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    Toast.makeText(AddPostFormActivity.this, "Post added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddPostFormActivity.this,Dashboard.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddPostFormActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method...

```
imageFolder.putFile(photoUri[i]).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                //Here you are get the download url 
                Task<Uri> urlTask =taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                final String sdownload_url = String.valueOf(downloadUrl);
                
                
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                addPostModel = new AddPostModel();
                        
              addPostModel.setCategories(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
                        addPostModel.setSubcategories(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
                        addPostModel.setTitle(name.getText().toString().trim());
                        addPostModel.setAuthor(author.getText().toString().trim());
                        addPostModel.setPrice(price.getText().toString().trim());
                        addPostModel.setDesc(desc.getText().toString().trim());
                        addPostModel.setUserUid(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                        addPostModel.setPhoneNumaber(mCurrentUser.getPhoneNumber());
                        addPostModel.setDateTime(date);
                        addPostModel.setImageUrl(photoUri[i].toString());//Here is the problem//
                        addPostModel.setKey(id);
                        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(addPostModel);

            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                Toast.makeText(AddPostFormActivity.this, "Post added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddPostFormActivity.this,Dashboard.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(AddPostFormActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```